# Installed pytorch with conda which changed my TF version to 1.13.0 now conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.0 not working?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Like I said in title I installed pytorch with conda install and that downgraded my tensorflow version to 1.13.0 and now conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.0 is not working how can I get the command to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have installed pyTorch in another virtual environment but since now it has been installed. 
I would recommend you to create a virtual environment and install TF plus other libraries in it. Because I am sure you would not use both PyTorch and TF in the same program for ML.

Comment: I ended up just uninstalling anaconda and installing tensorflow in root env and putting pytorch in another environment

Comment: So, did it help you fixing your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you try to install tensorflow with pip. `pip install -U tensorflow-gpu`

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

I am using pytorch, but my env has pytorch 1.2 + tensorflow 2.1